# Angular 5 Promise waiting to long for back end answer gets undefined

Tags: java, typescript, angular5, backend

I'm sending a POST request from front-end within a Promise using Angular 5 and the problem is that back-end service takes to long to answer and, even though the script keeps going on Java back-end, promise's results shows up as "undefined", kind of like it has a timeout on waiting.

It is expected this backend service to take a while to answer. So, I intend to show to user that request stills not completed. To do so, I would need the Promised to keep on waiting a few more moments on the service's answer.

Chrome's console show this

```
Loader Started - HTTP request: /api/example/exampleService

POST https://localhost:4200/api/example/exampleService net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error
Loader Finished - HTTP request: /api/example/exampleService
```

Comment: Typically you'd do this by polling across multiple requests, not relying on a single request to not time out. See e.g. https://farazdagi.com/2014/rest-and-long-running-jobs/.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase your timeout using a pipe in Angular:

```
this.http.post(API_URL, {headers: HEADER})
            .pipe(
                timeout(3000) //3 seconds
            );
```